# Ruby on Rails: Finding all topics in a certain category?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to find all topics in a one particular category, but I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way to do it:

```
Topic.all.select { |topic| topic.categories.include?(category) }
```

The above works for me but it seems that it takes MySQL a long time to find the records. Is there anything more efficient?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like right now you have a has_many relationship between topics and categories, when you need a many-to-many relationship.  Restructure your models like this:

```
# app/models/category.rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :topics
end

# app/models/topic.rb
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

Then create a join table **without** a primary key.  Create the new migration like so:

```
script/generate migration AddCategoriesTopicsJoinTable
```

And add these contents:

```
class AddCategoriesTopicsJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :categories_topics, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer :category_id
      t.integer :topic_id
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :categories_topics
  end
end
```

Notice the join table is named by combining the two table names, in alphabetical order.  That's how Rails will know how to find it automatically.

Now you can call `@category.topics` and get an array of the topics, and you can call `@topic.categories` and get the categories.  It works in both directions.

**UPDATE:** questions about many-to-many relationships in Rails have come up often enough that I wrote an article called [basic many-to-many associations](http://kconrails.com/2010/01/29/has_and_belongs_to_many-associations-in-ruby-on-rails/) to explain how to use `habtm` vs `has_many :through`, and the differences between them.